# .net - bluetooth communication with headphones

Tags: c#, .net, windows, bluetooth, airpods

Currently, I am working on a project where I need to enhance using Bluetooth headphones. For now, it's only AirPods 3 gen and 2 gen. And I want to perform two tasks. First, to track when the case is opened or the headphone is out of it. Second, to track when the pod is out of the ear (ear detection).

I did some research with ProtocolLogger on macOS and this is what I got.

---

So AirPods seem to send connect request automatically to macOS and then the system is reacting. How to achieve this in Windows?
[image: Connection request]

---

For ear detection. My AirPods 3 gen is sending this when the pod is out of the ear
[image]

And this when plugged again into the ear
[image]

For my AirPods, 2 gen functionality differs.
This is when the pod is out of the ear
[image]

And finally this when is back in the ear
[image]

So how to listen to all these commands that are sent from headphones in c#? And how to send AVRCP commands from code?

Comment: This has nothing to do with WinUI-3.